# DIV and <H3> tag issues styling issues

Tags: css, html

I'm struggling with an issue here, I feel like it's probably something very simple that I'm just missing because I have been looking at it for so long.  But here it goes:

I have multiple divs that contain Wijmo HTML 5 widgets.  I'm basically creating a dashboard and so far everything has gone very smoothly.  I have a Top Div which contains a full length widget, Two divs underneath that split the page in half, with multiple widgets within those. Now I'm trying to add one last div on the bottom that will run the full span of the page like the top div, but every time I add a  tag design to look like a header bar, the styling of that tag runs from the top of the two divs that separate the page to the very bottom.  I can't seem to figure out what I need to change to get this from happening.

Here are two images, showing before and after adding the  tag

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQndE.jpg

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwYCu.jpg

And then here is some of the css code,

```
.header-bar
{
background: #494949; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #6d6d6d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #787878), color-stop(100%, #6d6d6d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #6d6d6d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #6d6d6d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #6d6d6d 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, #787878 0%, #6d6d6d 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#787878', endColorstr='#6d6d6d', GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.10);
padding: 0.4em 0.4em;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
margin-right: 0.4em;
font-family: "Segoe UI" , Segoe, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

HTML Format:

```
    <section>
        <div id="top-fullspan">
            <!--Removed to shorten code-->
        </div>

        <div id="mainbody">
            <div id="body-left">
                <div id="body-left-top"></div>
                <div id="body-left-bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="body-right">
                <div id="body-right-top"></div>
                <div id="body-right-bottom">
                    <div id="body-right-bottom-lefthalf"></div>
                    <div id="body-right-bottom-righthalf"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-fullspan">
            <!--<h3 class="header-bar">Sentiment</h3>--> <!--Where issue is occuring-->
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div></div>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
```

EDIT: Added HTML Code to show structure.

Comment: We need to see the CSS & HTML structure.  But not all of it.  Reduce this down to a simple test case please.

Comment: How are the widgets set up? are they floated? You might be forgetting to clear a float?

Comment: I have the divs setup to float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a div to clear after the  main body div. something like.

```
<div id="mainbody">
        {...}
    </div>

<!-- Try adding this -->
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<!-- End -->
    <div id="bottom-fullspan">
        <!--<h3 class="header-bar">Sentiment</h3>--> <!--Where issue is occuring-->
    </div>
```

Of course, creating a clear class in a style sheet would be better but this would be quick way to determine if it is a clearing issue.

You can also try adding borders to every `<div>` element to see each div on the page and its true size.

```
div { border: 1px solid black;}
```

Comment: I'm just a little confused as to what was causing the issue still though?  Would you mind explaining what you think the issue was?  I just want to know for future reference :)

Comment: When using a  floating `<div>` or (any element),  the browser can be confused as to where the element height ends without a clearing element to follow. It is a good practice to add a clearing style after you add a float. Hope that makes sense.